# What happens if we derive Ord but not Eq while making a data type?

Tags: haskell

I understand that in haskell if we make a data type deriving Ord it should be deriving Eq as well, but why do we have to explicitly write both of them in the definition?

Comment: Sometimes you can provide a much faster `Eq` instance than the one which would be derived. The idea behind [interned](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/intern) strings (and other interned structures) is that you can compare them for equality in O(1) time. I could see a situation like that but slightly different, where you might want a standard `Ord` instance from `deriving` but a special `Eq` instance.

Answer (score 6):

One could plausibly derive `Ord` but instantiate `Eq` by hand:

```
data Foo = Foo deriving Ord
instance Eq Foo where
    _ == _ = True
```

I can't think of a place off-hand where this would be useful, but there's no reason to prevent it.

Comment: There's also a bit more flexible definition: `data Foo = ... deriving (Ord); instance Eq Foo where x == y = compare x y == EQ`. GHC then effectively autogenerates both instances.

Comment: (Of course, `deriving (Eq, Ord)` already does that, more or less, so that might not be super useful.)

Answer (score 2):

You are required to write `Eq` for the same reason that you have to write an instance for `Eq` before writing an instance for `Ord` (or at least before compiling it). It would be possible to deduce one, but that property does not apply to all typeclass contexts so you need to be explicit.

The compiler could easily know to derive `Eq` (and this would probably be fairly harmless), but it might cause some surprises to have an instance of a typeclass without explicitly asking for it. This could be very confusing if it somehow happened to more complicated typeclasses.

Comment: The bigger problem is that sometimes the superclass could be derived based on any of several subclasses. In that case, which one should it pick? For example, `Functor` could be derived from `Applicative` or from `Traversable` or from `Comonad`.

Comment: None of those can be automatically derived in a data declaration though?

Comment: @Tesseract, `Traversable` and `Functor` both can with suitable extensions.  Of course that means dfeuer's ambiguity can't happen in practice, but that seems more of a coincidence, and in principle it's an issue worth thinking about.